# Output amount of primes in array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm kind of a newbie at Java, and not very good at it.  It's a trial and error process for me.

I'm working on a Java program to output the amount of primes in an array.  I can get it to output the primes, but I want to also output the quantity of primes.  I tried to add each prime to an array list titled "primes" then return "primes.size()" at the end of my program.  It doesn't work as intended. The count is actually off.  When I create an array of 5 numbers, it outputs 3 primes, 2, 3, and 5.  But then it says I have 4 primes.  I think it might be counting 1 as a prime.   Because when I create an array of 20, the prime numbers output 2,3,5,7,11,13,17 and 19.  Then it says the total prime numbers = 9.  It should be 8 though.

Here's my code

```
public class Prime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("How big would you like the array? ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[num];
        ArrayList < Integer > primes = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

        //System.out.println("How Many threads? ");
        //int nThreads = scan.nextInt();  // Create variable 'n'  to handle whatever integer the user specifies.  nextInt() is used for the scanner to expect and Int.

        //Thread[] thread = new Thread[nThreads];     
        for (int n = 1; n <= array.length; n++) {
            boolean prime = true;

            for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
                if (n % j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (prime) {
                primes.add(n);
            }

            if (prime && n != 1) {

                System.out.println(n + "");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Total Prime numbers = " + primes.size());
        System.out.println("Prime Numbers within " + array.length);
    }
}
```

Forgive the sloppiness of it. I actually plan on adding multithreading to it, but I wanted to get this down first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do make a distinction between the decision of *printing* a number as prime and *adding* it to the prime list? They should be one and the same. You exclude 1 from printing, but not adding.

Comment: If you are a newbie in Java, can I suggest that you don't try to think about multithreading? Leave it until you have got the basics absolutely nailed, and then some.

Comment: One side note - you don't need the `array` variable since you use only its length and don't store any values in it. Simply remove it and use `num` instead of `array.length`.

Comment: Yes you are counting 1 as a prime. Start your for loop from 2 to ignore it: `for (int n = 2; n <= array.length; n++)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner  I hear ya, but I kind of have to do Multi-threading.   I understand it conceptually, not so much implementing. I've done it before with a lot of trial and error and help from the internet.

Answer (score 4):

You have included `1` in your array of primes, because you started the `n` for loop at `1`.  You don't print it because of the final `if` statement, but it's there in the `ArrayList`.

Start your `n` for loop with `n = 2`.  As a consequence, you won't need the final `if` statement, because `n` won't be `1` ever.  You could print the prime at the same time as you add it to the `ArrayList`.